# How to change computer domain without login?

Tags: windows, authentication, enterprise

I have changed domain of my windows pc out of curiosity. Now I can not login to enterprise account using this laptop. I need to change domain of my laptop back to its original domain.

Comment: You can't.  Only your domain administrators can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to login to the PC. I would try a local account.

When trying to login to a local account user the following for the user. This will use the local account.

Username: .\User

Side note: You will need to contact your help desk to get reconnected to your enterprise account as you need admin privileges to the domain to add a computer to it. Help desk should have a local account login and password as well.

Hope this helps!